# How to write a Haskell function that determine if a number is even or odd?

Tags: function, haskell, integer, boolean

i m trying to understand the haskell language and i m so confused with it, because i have the following exercise and can't even start with it:

> 1. `evenNat :: Integer -> Bool`, which takes a non-negative integer as input and
>    determines whether it is even.

(there's more but let's focus on this one for now)

> In all of these programs you are not allowed to use the built-in multiplication-, division-, or modulo-functions.

How should i start and can you give me some advice how to learn this language? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're supposed to use recursion. Eg for `evenNat`, define `evenNat 0`, then for an arbitrary (positive) input recurse on the number that's one smaller. That basically tells you how to do the first one, I'll leave the others to you :)

Comment: If you had access to some function called `substractLargestPossiblePowerOf2`, do you see how you could solve `evenNat` using recursion ? Have you read [this chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) or something similar ?

Comment: Silly question: Are bitwise operations banned? Because if not, `evenNat` is implementable with `x & 0x1 == 0` (or whatever syntax Haskell uses for bitwise ops). And the others are trivially implemented in terms of `evenNat`.

Answer (score 2):

An integer is even if and only if its low bit is 0. It's odd if and only if its low bit is 1. You can use a simple operation in `Data.Bits` to test this.

```
import Data.Bits
import Prelude hiding (even, odd)

even, odd :: Integer -> Bool
even x = ??
odd x = ??
```

That said, I think Robin Zigmond is probably right about the intention of this exercise. To get at that intent more directly, you can define your own numbers.

```
import Prelude hiding (Integer, even, odd)

data PNat
  = One
  | Succ PNat

data Integer
  = Negative PNat
  | Zero
  | Positive PNat
```

Now define

```
evenNat :: PNat -> Bool
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. `evenNat :: Integer -> Bool`, which takes a non-negative integer as input and determines whether it is even.

Just write down what you know:

```
evenNat :: Integer -> Bool
evenNat n | n < 0 = error "forbidden call to evenNat"
evenNat 0 = True
evenNat 1 = False
evenNat 2 = True
evenNat 3 = .....
.....
```

That's a perfectly good start, except, we have no hope of ever enumerating all the necessary cases explicitly, to cover all possible inputs.

But let's stop for a moment. How would we complete the `evenNat 3 = ...` definition? We could certainly put the explicit answer there, `False`. But we could also notice that `False == not True`, and `True == evenNat 2`, so that

```
evenNat 3 = False 
          = not True
          = not (evenNat 2)
          = not (evenNat (3 - 1))
```

and actually,

```
evenNat 2 = True 
          = not False
          = not (evenNat 1)
          = not (evenNat (2 - 1))
```

which follows the same pattern exactly.

And there you have it! All that's left is, *generalize!* by turning concrete data into variables, so that we get one more -- ultimate -- clause,

```
evenNat n = not (...... ( ... - ... ))
```

and that's that.

Answer (score 2):

### A modest attempt at efficiency:

Let's accept Robin's premise that recursion is the actual subject here.

Recursion consists in replacing a comparatively hard problem by an easier problem, or maybe by a list of easier problems.

For example, `evenNat 43` is the negation of `evenNat 42`. If we go down that route, after 40+ steps we reach `evenNat 0` which is known to be `True`. That scheme works, but it can be a bit slow for large numbers.

A faster approach could consist in substracting, at each step, the largest possible power of 2 from the number at hand. Such a substraction does not change the even character of a number. So 43 is even if and only if (43-32) = 11 is even. Next, we consider (11-8) = 3. So it definitely looks like a faster, if somewhat more complex, approach.

First, we need the sequence of powers of 2, up to the number at hand. This can be done, of course, recursively:

```
powersOf2UpToN :: Integer -> [Integer]
powersOf2UpToN n =
    let  -- defining auxiliary function sq:
         sq m pwrs = if (head pwrs > m)    -- if reached big enough
                         then  (tail pwrs) -- then stop and return result
                         else -- augment:
                              let  hps = head pwrs  in  sq m ((hps+hps):pwrs)
    in  (sq n [2])
```

Note that I am using `(hps+hps)` instead of `(2*hps)` because the rules of the exercise ban native multiplication.

Essentially, we prepend larger and larger powers of 2 to the power sequence as long as we remain below the number at hand. Recall in Haskell, prepending an element to a list is a cheap operation.

Testing under the `ghci` interpreter:

```
$ ghci
 λ> 
 λ> :load q64544005.hs
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> powersOf2UpToN 337
 [256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2]
 λ>
```

Next, we must implement the function that substracts the largest possible power of 2. Such a function would take a *(number, powers of 2)* pair, and return an “improved” pair, that is with a smaller number and a shortened power list. The type signature would be like:

```
reduce2 :: (Integer, [Integer]) -> (Integer, [Integer])`
```

The overall logic would be:

```
reduce2 (n, pwrs) =
    if (null pwrs)     -- did we just run out of powers of 2 ?
        then  (n, [])  -- nothing left to do
        else  if ((head pwrs) <= n)  -- return a lower n if possible
              ...
```

**Please pause reading here and see if you can fill in the blanks.**

---

Solution: when possible, we substract the largest remaining power of 2, which happens to lie at the head of the (decreasing) list.

```
reduce2 (n, pwrs) =
    if (null pwrs)
        then  (n, [])  -- nothing left to do
        else  if ((head pwrs) <= n)  -- return a lower n if possible
                  then  reduce2  ((n - (head pwrs)), tail pwrs)
                  else  reduce2  (n, tail pwrs)
```

The mechanics of `reduce2` are key. So to help with the understanding, let's leverage Haskell's handy little tracing facility.

In the code below, the expression `DT.trace msg res` evaluates to just `res`, with the side effect of printing `msg`. Yes, side effects are normally forbidden in Haskell, but the tracing facility enjoys a special privilege.

So here is a tracing version of our `reduce2` function:

```
import qualified  Debug.Trace  as  DT
type DebugMsg = String

traceReduce2 :: DebugMsg -> (Integer, [Integer]) -> (Integer, [Integer])
traceReduce2 msg (n, pwrs) =
    let  res = if (null pwrs)
                   then  (n, [])
                   else  let  msg1 = (show n) ++ "  " ++ (show pwrs)
                              rem  = n - (head pwrs)
                         in   if ((head pwrs) <= n)
                                  then  traceReduce2 msg1 (rem, tail pwrs)
                                  else  traceReduce2 msg1 (n,   tail pwrs)
    in  DT.trace msg res
```

Testing our tracing version:

```
 λ> 
 λ> traceReduce2 "TOP" (337, (powersOf2UpToN 337))
 TOP
 337  [256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2]
 81  [128,64,32,16,8,4,2]
 81  [64,32,16,8,4,2]
 17  [32,16,8,4,2]
 17  [16,8,4,2]
 1  [8,4,2]
 1  [4,2]
 1  [2]
 (1,[])
 λ>
```

So we're almost done. After processing all powers of 2, a value of 0 or 1 remains as the left side of the pair. We can proceed to write our `evenNat` function:

```
evenNat :: Integer -> Bool
evenNat n = 
    let  (remainder, ys) = reduce2 (n, powersOf2UpToN n)
    in
         -- here, remainder is set to 0 if and only if n is even
         ...
```

and the rest should be easy.

Comment: I'll read through this shortly after some RL stuff but it's a nice idea. I had it in the back of my mind as well -- 2 `not`s in a row are the same as 4, etc, so, jump over that somehow, doubling the distance  progressively with each call/attempt...

Comment: but your way also works, obviously. :) (you could use pattern matching instead of explicit head and tail for a cleaner looking code, but that's just details...)

Comment: @WillNess - Thanks for the suggestion. Also, it is probably possible to maintain the half-number within the carried state. Pop 512 from the power list, add the next power in line, 256, to the half-number. So we could use the same ideas to get some `splitNat` function that would map 21 into (1,10). That could be used to implement recursive addition-based multiplication, should we want to extend that neat exercise.